# Initializing external 1TB hard disk with MBR option

Tags: external-hard-drive, mbr, gpt

I have an 1TB WD my passport hard disk(HD). I connected that HD to my laptop this morning and it didn't show in My Computer. After trying for several times, I went to disk management, and as soon as it opened it said I need to initialize my disk.

What does initialize exactly means? If I need to initialize which option do I need to choose MBR or GPT?
Will I be able to recover my data after initializing the HD by using recovery tools like recuva or any other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- "**Initialize Disk**" is an option given by "**Disk Management**" only to a new drive.
- Initializing the disk will erase all the data on your drive, and will ask you to create a new partition / partitions so as to make the disk usable.
- If you had data on your drive and if it was important, and Windows is showing you this option you need to consider taking your drive to a data recovery pro.
- If NOT, you can try recovering you data using another host like Linux (Live Knoppix or Ubuntu).

If you consider initializing your disk, and risk losing all your data:

- You should use "MBR" (Master Boot Record).
- Initializing basically means, "begin using a brand new drive, which is not partitioned along with Windows"

Comment: is recovery possible after initialization?

Comment: No, it is not possible! Read this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-hardware/what-does-initialization-do-to-a-hard-disk/4c01e30c-37fb-4884-b124-ac2d59078008

Comment: thnx @aliasagar !!!

Comment: Is it true that the data is still there even after initializing? so can it be recovered? Read this: http://www.sweetwater.com/insync/differences-between-format-initialize/

Comment: The data still exists, but the partition table is re-written and the disk is shown as blank. Now the data is dangling at this point; as in we do NOT where it exactly lies making it NOT recoverable from a recovery point of view. Hope this helps, and answers your question! :)

Comment: It is true.  Recovery isn't guaranteed though.